# Let$(a,b,c)$ be a nonzero vector in the row space of a $3\times 3$ matrix $B$. Show that the nullspace of $B$ is a subset of the plane $ax+by+cz=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $(a$ $b$ $c)$ be a nonzero vector that belongs to the row space of
>   a  $3\times 3$ matrix $B$. Show that the nullspace of $B$ is a subset of the
>   plane $ax + by + cz = 0.$

My thoughts so far:
Let $\alpha=(x$ $y$ $z)$ be a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $A.$ If I can show $(a$ $b$ $c)\alpha=0$ then the proof is completed. However I don't know how to utilize this piece of information:

> $(a$ $b$ $c)$ be a nonzero vector that belongs to the row space of a 
>   $3\times 3$ matrix $B$

Desperately need a hint on this, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that the set of vectors in the plane are **orthogonal** to the normal vector. What can you say about the orthogonality between the rows of a matrix and a vector in it's nullspace?

Comment: the rowspace of a matrix is the orthogonal complement to its nullspace?

Comment: Yes. Does that help you answer your question?

Comment: That definitely helps, thanks!